# In winform button needs to be clicked twice for firing event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a buttton on the click event of which I am calling a function.I have set the accept button property to that button.But it is not firing the event on single click.

```
 private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        try
        {
            //Function call for validating the textboxes entry
            ValidateForm();

            if(lblMessage.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                //Function call for binding the dropdown with all DB names 
                BindDBDropDown();

                //Function call for binding the operation names in dropdown 
                SetOperationDropDown();
            }
            else
            {
                //Else give the error message to user
                lblMessage.Text = "Invalid Credentials";
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //All the exceptions are handled and written in the EventLog.
            EventLog log = new EventLog("Application");
            log.Source = "MFDBAnalyser";
            log.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
        }
    }


public void BindDBDropDown()
{

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder objConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        objConnectionString.DataSource = txtHost.Text;
        objConnectionString.UserID = txtUsername.Text;
        objConnectionString.Password = txtPassword.Text;

        SqlConnection sConnection = new SqlConnection(objConnectionString.ConnectionString);

        //If connected then give this message to user
        lblMessage.Visible = true;
        lblMessage.Text = "You are connected to the SQL Server....";

        try
        {
            //To Open the connection.
            sConnection.Open();

            //Query to select the list of databases.
            string selectDatabaseNames = @"SELECT 
                                                NAME 
                                             FROM 
                                                [MASTER]..[SYSDATABASES]";

            //Create the command object
            SqlCommand sCommand = new SqlCommand(selectDatabaseNames, sConnection);

            //Create the data set 
            DataSet sDataset = new DataSet("master..sysdatabases");

            //Create the dataadapter object
            SqlDataAdapter sDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectDatabaseNames, sConnection);
            sDataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "master..sysdatabases");

            //Fill the dataset
            sDataAdapter.Fill(sDataset);

            //Bind the database names in combobox
            DataViewManager dsv = sDataset.DefaultViewManager;

            //Provides the master mapping between the sourcr table and system.data.datatable
            cmbDatabases.DataSource = sDataset.Tables["master..sysdatabases"];
            cmbDatabases.DisplayMember = "NAME";
            cmbDatabases.ValueMember = ("NAME");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //All the exceptions are handled and written in the EventLog.
            EventLog logException = new EventLog("Application");
            logException.Source = "MFDBAnalyser";
            logException.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
            MessageBox.Show ("Login Failed!!", "Error Occured");
        }
        finally
        {
            //If connection is not closed then close the connection
            if(sConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                sConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anybody help me out??

Comment: Where are you registering the event handler? Can you post that code?

Comment: "Clicked twice", is that twice as in double-click, or as in two separate single-clicks?

Comment: Try to add MessageBox.Show() at the first line of your btnConnect_Click method. Tell us what will happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Uh, on the first click, does `lblMessage` contain any text?**

Because if not, the first time you run it, it will fail the conditional test and insert the string "Invalid Credentials" into the label. Then, the second time you run it, it will pass the conditional test and call the `BindDBDropDown` method as you're expecting.

Specifically, this section of your code:

```
if(lblMessage.Text != string.Empty)
{
    //Function call for binding the dropdown with all DB names 
    BindDBDropDown();

    //Function call for binding the operation names in dropdown 
    SetOperationDropDown();
}
else
{
    //Else give the error message to user
    lblMessage.Text = "Invalid Credentials";
}
```

I assume that you're either trying to check that the contents of a textbox where the user has entered their credentials are not empty, or that you want to make sure an error message is not currently displayed in `lblMessage`. Make sure that your code accurately reflects your intentions!